Visually simulate a widget test of a Flutter package
I have a Flutter package and want to be able to run widget tests (not integration) on a platform (web, desktop, etc.) to debug and see visually when a test is being executed. It doesn't necessarily have to be a platform. If there is a tool that visually demonstrates a widget test running would be fine as well.
I can use flutter run test/a_widget_test.dart on a normal project but that's not possible in a package. And I can't add a platform with flutter create --platforms=web . to a package since the package template doesn't support that.
